# Sync textarea text with jstree nodes

Tags: javascript, performance, html

I'm trying to retrieve all the nodes of a [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/) and display the data on a `textarea`, this strange code is working fine, but the execution is very slow, it takes an average of ~3 seconds for the `textarea` receive the incoming data from the jstree, i would like to know if is there any way to improve the peformance

**Dependencies:** jQuery 3.3.1 and jsTree 3.3.5

> **UPDATE:** I made some improvements on the code by replacing the excessive event listeners with a single `syncNodes()` function

#### HTML `<body>`:

```
<!-- Here is where the user select a command -->
<select id="sel_cmd" onchange="exec(this.value)">
    <option value=""># Select a command #</option>
    <option value="inclib">Include library</option>
</select>

<!-- jstree container -->
<div id="jstree">
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- The textarea that will receive jstree nodes data -->
<textarea id="jstree-code" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
```

#### JS file

```
// Initialize jstree
$("#jstree").jstree({
    core: {
        'check_callback': true
    }
});

// (FUNCTION) Create jstree nodes
function createNode(tree_id, parent_node, new_node_id, new_node_text, position) {
    $(tree_id).jstree("create_node", $(parent_node), {
        text: new_node_text,
        id: new_node_id
    }, position, false, false);
}

// Get all nodes on the jstree and send their data to textarea
function syncNodes() {
    $("#jstree-code").val("");
    var nodesArray = []
    $(
        $("#jstree").jstree("get_json", $("#jstree"), { flat: true })
    ).each(function(index, value) {
        var node = $("#jstree").jstree().get_node(this.id);
        var txt = node.text.trim();
        var lvl = node.parents.length;
        var idx = index;
        nodesArray += "text = " + txt + " // index = " + idx + " // level = " + lvl + "\n";
    });
    $("#jstree-code").val(nodesArray);
}

// ******************************

syncNodes();

function exec(op) {
    switch (op) {
        case "inclib":
            var lib = prompt("Library name:");
            createNode("#jstree", "#jstree", `${lib}`, `${lib}`, "last");
            syncNodes();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. does [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/p8VEH5sZVZVWCBHF6YQg?p=preview) still exhibit the slowness you observe? If not, can you alter it so that it does?

Comment: It's running a lot smoother, thanks! @SamOnela

Comment: Hmm... all I did was try to recreate the scenario you laid out... did you alter anything on that plunker?

Comment: I just took the plunker code and kept working on it (adding new features) if you wanna take a look, i can send you a link